# how to automatically get significant words in a string using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to produce keywords automatically from a given title in PHP if a form is submitted. I want to get keywords which are not included in stopwords in mysql.

example:

My title is: **How to get related questions using title using MATCH() AGAINST()**

The result should be : **questions, title, match**

Please see my code below:

```
<?php
$title = "How to get related questions using MATCH() AGAINST()";
$explode(' ', $title);
$stopwords = array('second', 'first'); //more entries here 
$keywords = '';
foreach($explode as $word)
{
  if( ! in_array($word , $stopwords))
  {
     $keywords .= $keywords;
  }
}
echo " KEYWORDS : {$keywords}";
?>
```

Is this possible in MYSQL?

Comment: is it possible in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Explode doesn't work that way. It should be something like this:

```
$titlewords = explode(' ',$title);
```

Now you have an array with the words. You can use array_filter to clear out the empty ones if you want.